# Cufflinks: how to subplot heatmaps w/ Cufflinks in Jupyter/ipython Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, heatmap, plotly, subplot

I have read the [Cufflinks examples](https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/cufflinks/). The only subplots examples are generated from a single DataFrame with a `subplots=True` parameter and an optional `shape` parameter (i.e. `df.iplot(..., subplots=True, shape=(...), ...)`. As I understand it, the mechanism is that when `subplots=True` is provided, each column of the DataFrame is plotted as a subplot.

Now, about heatmaps in Cufflinks. The example in the same link shows that the `DataFrame` of a heatmap of `N * M` is simply an `N * M` DataFrame where the column names and indexes tells the x and y coordiates and the values are the "heat" of each cell of the grid.

Combining the two, it seems that if I have two heatmaps (thus two DataFrames), I cannot plot both in a subplot-fashion, because subplots require a single DataFrame and I cannot combine two heatmap DataFrames into one.

Anyone has any idea how it might work?

BTW, I also tried `plotly.offline.iplot(..., subplots=True, ...)` and the parameter is not supported.

**EDIT**

There is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42312634/how-to-setup-plotly-two-horizontal-subplots-containing-heatmaps-so-that-they-don) (from me, too) asking about doing the same in plotly, which got answered. So if you are working w/ plotly directly then that's the answer you might want to take a look.

This question is about using Cufflinks to achieve the same. It still seems impossible (or at least very difficult) to me.

Comment: I agree with you, having the same problem, can't manage to find a function/method `facet_wrap()`-like (in ggplot R package). I'm guessing that's what you are aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
import cufflinks as cf
df1=cf.datagen.heatmap()
df2=cf.datagen.heatmap()
cf.subplots([df1.figure(kind='heatmap'),df2.figure(kind='heatmap')]).iplot()
```

You can do this with as many heatmaps, and you can also use the `shape` parameters.