# How to setup Plotly two horizontal subplots containing heatmaps so that they don't share a colorscale?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly

I have two heatmaps. Their values are in totally different scale, so should not share a colorscale. I tried to create a plotly figure w/ two subplots (arranged horizontally) and put each of my heatmaps into one of the subplot. However, the two heatmap shares the same colorscale to the right of the heatmap on the right. The colorscale show two sets of labels overlapped w/ each other. What I'd like to see is that there are two colorscales, one to the right of each heatmap.

My code is below. Anyone seeing a problem here?

```
fig = plotly.tools.make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)

fig.append_trace(mm, 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(sm, 1, 2)

plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```

I have tried to set `share_xaxes` and `share_yaxes` to `False` explicitly. Didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could specify the `x` [position](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#heatmap-colorbar-x) of the colorbar explicitly, see the example below.

The figure looks better in the notebook, perhaps one should also move the right plot?

[image: moved it]

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()

mm = go.Heatmap(
        z=[[1, 20, 30],
           [20, 1, 60],
           [30, 60, 1]],
        colorbar = dict(x=0.45), 
    colorscale='Viridis'
    )
sm = go.Heatmap(
        z=[[1, 2, 3],
           [2, 1, 6],
           [3, 6, 1]]
    )
fig = plotly.tools.make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)
fig.append_trace(mm, 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(sm, 1, 2)

plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to @maximilian-peters' answer (not sure how to refer to a stackoverflow username here). I followed your suggestion of using colorbar.x and it worked out nicely. The `0.45` positioning is nice, too. If the two heatmap happen to share the y axis then we can use `share_yaxes=True` so that the colorbar of heatmap #1 won't overlap w/ the y axis of heatmap #2. Then, for the colorbar of heatmap #2 I used `1.0` as its `x` position, which seemed to match the distance between the heatmap and the colorbars for both pairs.

Comment: Not sure if the reference to Maximilian Peters worked @maximilian-peters Thanks man!

Answer (score 3):

I found this solution: for 3 heatmaps, I created a grid of 6 boxes, in order to manually place on the side the colorbars of each heatmap :

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=6,
                    subplot_titles=("Web", "Magasin", "Email"),
                    specs=[[{}, None, {}, None, {}, None]],
                    shared_yaxes=True)
```

then I drew the heatmaps by defining each colorbar :

```
fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(
    z=df_web.values,
    x=df_web.columns.tolist(),
    y=df_web.index.tolist(),
    colorscale='RdBu',
    reversescale=True,
    colorbar = dict(x=0.27, title='Nb moyen', thickness=15)), row=1, col=1
)

fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(
    z=df_mag.values,
    x=df_mag.columns.tolist(),
    y=df_mag.index.tolist(),
    colorscale='RdBu',
    reversescale=True,
    colorbar = dict(x=0.62, title='Nb moyen', thickness=15)), row=1, col=3
)

fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(
    z=df_email.values,
    x=df_email.columns.tolist(),
    y=df_email.index.tolist(),
    colorscale='RdBu',
    reversescale=True,
    colorbar = dict(x=0.97, title='Nb moyen', thickness=15)), row=1, col=5
)
```

and finally I defined positions :

```
fig.update_layout(title_text='Répartition par jour et heure', title_x=0.5,
                height=250, margin=dict(l=0,r=0,b=50,t=25),
                xaxis=dict(
        domain=[0, 0.27]
    ),
    xaxis2=dict(
        domain=[0.35, 0.62]
    ),
    xaxis3=dict(
        domain=[0.7, 0.97]
    ))
```

Result :
[image: heatmaps whith separated colorbars]

Comment: Do you have any idea how to make each plot square-shaped ?